# Decode or identify this code

Tags: php, base64, decode

I was able to decode my codes on 'base64_decode',json_decode and many. But after that I got another coded output which went like..

```
phone==METMxEjMxTTMxUjN4Ag=2gTO3UzN5kzM1gDOwATMxUzN

1ATNwATM2ETM1cDNxETO5IDMxYTMxgDO5QDO3ITN1czN1MDMxYTN5ETM5kjNxEjN

wEzM1QDMxYzN1YTO3kDMxgTMxcTN2ETMxcDO4IjMxcTN4YjN2EDOjEjM4IDOwcjN
```

I am stuck here..  any idea about this code is belong to which? to decode like auto identify the code or auto decode any code

This code was found once i run one ISO app which is send it out (my mobile number) to the sever .. i was monitor it through Charles proxy. I was think its an base64 code due the same app use base64 and json as well for all receiving txt
here the request on Charles proxy look like

```
POST /Devs/me/enc/blk.php HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Cookie: sucuric_prtmpcb=1
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 183
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: %D9%85%D9%86%D9%88%20%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%82/4 CFNetwork/711.5.6  Darwin/14.0.0

phone==METMxEjMxTTMxUjN4Ag=2gTO3UzN5kzM1gDOwATMxUzN

1ATNwATM2ETM1cDNxETO5IDMxYTMxgDO5QDO3ITN1czN1MDMxYTN5ETM5kjNxEjN

wEzM1QDMxYzN1YTO3kDMxgTMxcTN2ETMxcDO4IjMxcTN4YjN2EDOjEjM4IDOwcjN
```

Thanks.
Hope you'll reply..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have to reverse the string and then decode as Base64:

This part:

> NjcwODI4MjEjODE2NjY4NTcxMjI4ODcxMTE2NTcxMTgxMDk3OTY1NzYxMDQ1MzEw
>
> NjExNjk5MTE5NTYxMDM1Nzc1NTI3ODQ5ODgxMTYxMDI5OTExNDc1MTE2MTAwNTA1
>
> NzUxMTAwODg1Mzk5NzU3OTg2

Translates to:

> 67082821#816668571228871116571181097965761045310611699119561035775527849881161029911475116100505751100885399757986

Since it returns all digits, except for one hash, it is highly probable that this is how it should be decoded.

The last part has some problems, first because it does not have a multiple of 4 characters (as required for base64). Still I could extract this part, still in reverse:

> NjUxMTTxMjEx

Translates to:

> 65114ñ211

But it seems unlikely that the message should have *ñ* in it.
Besides this part, only these bits are unexplained:

> =gA4
>
> MTEM==

Note that `TEM=` corresponds to `LC`, but that is all I can see in it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it is of use to you.